# how to get a PFUsers with multiple constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, geolocation, pfuser

i want to query a PFUser class where i have column showmeonmap that the user can choose if he want others to see him on the  map and another column with the geopoint i i want to get all the users that want to show  them  selfs and  are in radius of 50 KM of the current user is there anyway to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
[query whereKey:@"showmeonmap" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true];
[query whereKey:@"myLocation" nearGeoPoint:currentUserGeoPoint withinKilometers:50.0];
```

Read the docs: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html

You'll have to create a PFGeoPoint equal to the current location.